# How to limit frame rate for all games on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, performance, graphics

### Affected OS

- [Linux Mint 19.1 "Tessa" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=261), based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. (Unimportant, but later updated to 19.3 version.)

  the above system was later upgraded to:
- [Linux Mint 20.2 "Uma" - Cinnamon (64-bit)](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=288), based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. (This is my primary OS now.)

---

### Related Hardware

- [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit): [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/homepage.html), [Core 7th gen (Kaby Lake)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/95544/7th-generation-intel-core-i7-processors.html), [i7-7700HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html), base clock 2.80 GHz, max [Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) 3.80 GHz, [Smart Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Smart_cache) 6 MB
- [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit): [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/), [GeForce GTX 1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/10-series/), [Max-Q Design](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/gaming-laptops/max-q/), 6 GB [GDDR5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR5_SDRAM) [VRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_RAM_(dual-ported_DRAM))
- Screen: 4K laptop 15.6 inch display (UHD 3840 x 2160)

---

### Problem

There are about **200 - 300 FPS** while playing any non-GPU-heavy game(s), so I'm thinking **there is a lot of power being wasted**, and my hardware is overheating if such a game is in the foreground for many hours straight. Additionally, even if I don't pay the electricity bills, I think my hardware is more prone to fault if playing on a maximum frame rate, which in ordinary games can be the above-stated, hardly believable, 200 - 300 FPS.

---

### Question

How can I set an FPS limit for all games on my Nvidia-based hardware? If possible even, to name a few such games?

For example, **NOT an advertisement**, [Hexcells franchise](https://store.steampowered.com/sub/50074/) uses so little GPU, and I tested my solution below on these games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/)-specific solution

**Disclaimer**: The use of an official driver package from the repository, NOT from a PPA, is recommended by me. You can learn how to install or update your drivers in my other question here: [How to install the latest Nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/542360/126755)

---

### Important Notice

Disclaimer: **This solution has been verified and tested only on one Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 based system**. If you have an older one, DO NOT FOLLOW; use caution on newer versions too.

---

### Solution for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 based systems

This solution utilizes [V-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync) (Vertical Synchronization). If you don't like using it, this solution is not for you.

Thank you, [Xander](https://stackexchange.com/users/243806/xander), for the comment on enabling [V-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync). With this hint, I was able to find out, that I only need to do the following steps.

1. Create the following new (if not yet existing) file in your favorite text editor:

   ```
   /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf
   ```
2. Put this single line in there, save and close the file; in case the file exists already, then ensure this line is there:

   ```
   options nvidia-drm modeset=1
   ```
3. Update all of your `initramfs` images with:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```

   or if you only want to test it, you can update just the latest image with:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
4. Reboot your system.
5. The [V-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync) shall be on now, verify with:

   ```
   sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset
   ```

It will say:

- > `Y`

if [V-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync) is **On**

- > `N`

if [V-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing#V-sync) is **Off**

---

You should be done now, **capped to your display refresh rate** (usually 60).

In spite, I am satisfied with this solution, feel free to add your own (AMD-specific, Intel-specific, whatever...) to make this question useful for others.