# What are linux-modules-nvidia for?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, kernel-modules, proprietary-drivers

System: Linux Mint 20 "Ulyana" - Cinnamon (64-bit), [link for details](https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=281), based on Ubuntu 20.04

---

As outlined in my answer in [How to install the latest Nvidia drivers on Linux Mint 19 / 20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542361/126755), it is also possible to install / list available Nvidia drivers with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers list
```

which right now returns:

```
nvidia-driver-440-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-440-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-435, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-435-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-418-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-418-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-450, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-390, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-450-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-450-server-generic-hwe-20.04)
```

From this list, I do have *generic-way* installed `nvidia-driver-450`, but apparently missing the kernel modules provided by `linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04`, so my question is rather direct:

What do these additional drives or whatever they are, supposed to be doing, and do I *want* them?

Additional sources:

- Ubuntu: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic-hwe-20.04

Comment: This question seems to be *highly specific* to the exact way that Ubuntu handles the proprietary binary nvidia drivers. As such, I'd recommend this move to askubuntu.com where it's 1) more likely someone may know the answer and 2) the answer will be relevant to a larger percentage of its visitors

Comment: @Shadur It is Linux Mint 20, so no AskUbuntu...