# Nvidia drivers won't work on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, compatibility

My nvidia drivers won't work. They worked just fine before my last update. I have been trying to get them to work again but with no success.

if I run:

`nvidia-settings`

I get this error:

`ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded`

if I run:

`nvidia-smi`

I get this error:

`NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

I tried to install the default drivers using: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, which installs the 390 version. However i read somewhere that this driver isn't compatible with the more up to date linux kernel.

Then i tried installing the ppa and a more updated nvidia driver (after purging the old nvidia packages)

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430
```

But this won't work as well. I actually read that this drivers don't support my graphics card. Is there anything i can do to get my card working again?

My card is a GeForce GT 635M and am using Linux Mint Ulyssa

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542360/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-linux-mint-19-20 answer your question? Nvidia also specifically updates the 390 legacy driver to support all recent kernels; its purpose is to ensure older GPUs such as yours can function with new operating systems [- From Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/legacy-gpu/).

Answer (score 1):

Try `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`. It should open a GUI menu where you can select proprietary drivers (like nvidia). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at [How to fix Ubuntu NVIDIA driver is not loaded](https://dev.to/simonpham/how-to-fix-ubuntu-nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-2ipp)
by Simon Pham (at "DEV Community"). 
Summary:

Check if NVIDIA prime is installed with:

```bash
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

Then run these commands:

```bash
sudo prime-select nvidia
sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

(If you get a "no such file or directory" error, ignore it for now;
it should be OK.  After it's done running, reboot and run this command:

```bash
nvidia-smi
```

If you get a list of information, then it should be fixed.