# Linux Mint 20.2 not recognizing NVIDIA GTX 660ti even with drivers installed

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphics

So I have a Linux Mint machine with a Ryzen 5600G CPU with integrated graphics. I just recently got a GTX 660ti from a friend, and I'm trying to set it up, and the driver seems to be loading (running nvidia-smi gives the following):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.74       Driver Version: 470.74       CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   33C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     67MiB /  3015MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, a message on boot when the card is installed mentions that the system is running without video hardware acceleration, so the CPU is doing all the graphical heavy lifting without the help of its iGPU.

So it seems like it knows the card is there, it's just not letting it do anything. Any ideas? I tried older nvidia drivers, nouveau, installing with the .run file from nvidia, even updating the kernel to 5.11, nothing has worked.

Edit: running `lspci | grep -i vga` outputs

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Try going to BIOS and changing the default graphics device.

Comment: I changed the BIOS integrated graphics settings from "Auto" to "Disabled" but it didn't fix the problem. I did not see an option like changing the default graphics device. My motherboard is a Gigabyte A520M-DS3H

Comment: Try to post your question here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Try this in my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542361/126755

Comment: I have already done both your recommended options to no avail

Comment: install mainline kernel. don't use mint

Comment: Please add the output of `dmesg -t | egrep -i "nvidia|nouveau"` and `lsmod | egrep "nvidia|nouveau"`